# Converting from list to numeric?

Tags: r

I have a file:

```
file<-read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/file.csv",head=T)

mode(file)
"list"

file<- file[,-1:2]
```

I would like to convert file to numeric mode to make the built in columnames disappear. Is this possible to do somehow?

My goal is that when I list some element in the file e.g. `file[,2:4]` then it should display only the numbers but not the column names.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly. `unname()` removes names. You could flatten your data to a numeric vector using `as.vector(as.matrix(file))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is all numeric (aside from the first two columns you want to drop), you can easily convert the data frame into an array:

```
x <- as.matrix(file[, -2:-1])
head(x)

            a1        b1        c1        d1        e1        f1        g1        h1        i1
[1,] 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
[2,]  99.33333  99.05363 100.00000  98.58044  97.56944  97.64706  97.34579  98.66039  98.12500
[3,]  98.70934 104.77707 103.57143  99.15429  98.93238 103.61446 101.28008 101.35780 100.33121
[4,] 103.92259 100.30395  98.85057  99.42370  99.64029 101.93798 100.94793 105.43085  98.09548
[5,]  98.74182  99.69697 101.16279  99.11894  99.09025 101.14068  98.74797  99.14148  97.07481
[6,]  99.38838 101.51976 101.14943 101.16959 100.55377  99.62406 100.63395 100.86595 100.34667
```

It is easy to subset arrays in the way you requested. Try this:

```
x[1:3, 2:5]
            b1       c1        d1        e1
[1,] 100.00000 100.0000 100.00000 100.00000
[2,]  99.05363 100.0000  98.58044  97.56944
[3,] 104.77707 103.5714  99.15429  98.93238
```

Since the column names in an array isn't in fact part of the data, I would usually keep the column names if they are informative.  However, you can change the column names, including to NULL values:

```
colnames(x) <- NULL
x[1:3, 2:5]

         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 100.00000 100.0000 100.00000 100.00000
[2,]  99.05363 100.0000  98.58044  97.56944
[3,] 104.77707 103.5714  99.15429  98.93238
```

Comment: yes but now still there are the a1 b1 c1 names instead I would like to have [,1] [,2] [,3]